# Replacing decimal values in dataframe with different strings if they fit in a range

Tags: python, pandas, loops, replace, range

How can I replace values in my dataframe if the value is in a certain range?
i.e I want to replace all values `0<i<=0.01` with three stars, `0.01<i<=0.05` with two stars and `0.05<i<=0.1` with one star.

This is my DataFrame:

```
C=pd.DataFrame({'A':[0.0001,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.075,0.1], 'B':[0.0001,0.01,0.025,0.05,0.075,0.1]})
```

First i tried to replace the values using:

```
C[((C.loc[:,:]<=0.01) & (C.loc[:,:]>0))]='***'
C[((C.loc[:,:]<=0.05) & (C.loc[:,:]>0.01))]='**'
C[((C.loc[:,:]<=0.1) & (C.loc[:,:]>0.05))]='*'
```

But this operation only works once. Once there are strings in the dataframe the `<=` operator doesnt work anymore and yields this error

> '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

So I thought that I can create a for loop, but there I had problems modelling the range, since `range()` only takes integers as input values. Then I tried to fix it with `np.arange()`. Since I do not know the stepsize, I cannot place it as input argument in `np.arange()`, but experimenting with very small stepsizes, had a strange behavior, i.e I did:

```
for index,rows in C.iterrows():
    for i in rows:
        if  i in np.arange(0,0.011, 0.00001):
            C=C.replace(i,'***')
        elif i in np.arange(0.05,0.1, 0.000001) :
            C=C.replace(i,'**')
C
```

which had as output:

```
    A       B
0   ***     ***
1   ***     ***
2   0.025   0.025
3   **      **
4   0.075   0.075
5   0.1     0.1
```

So it worked for the whole if statement, but only for the first value which is affected by the elif statement. Please help, how can I achieve this?

Comment: It looks like your dataframe has some string values. You can try `pd.to_numeric` to convert those into float.

Comment: well at the bginning it contains only floats (see the example provided) and then i want to fill it with strings.. so obiously after calling `C[((C.loc[:,:]<=0.01) & (C.loc[:,:]>0))]='***` it gets partially filled with strings and the operation wont work a second time, same applies for the for loop after the if condition was met

Comment: Ah, I see. Have a look at `pd.cut` with `labels` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the dataframe into numeric as @QuangHoang suggests, post this you can try with [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
c1=C.le(.01)
c2=C.gt(.01)&C.le(.05)
c3=C.gt(.05)&C.le(.1)
s=np.select([c1,c2,c3],['***','**','*'])
```

---

```
C[:]=s
print(C)
```

---

```
     A    B
0  ***  ***
1  ***  ***
2   **   **
3   **   **
4    *    *
5    *    *
```

Comment: your `lt` and `le` are not all correct and complete.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 thanks, it was missing a `C.gt(0` check. :) updated now

Comment: if you use `c1=C.le(0.01)` and `c3=C.gt(0.05)&le(0.1)` it is exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: Comment above is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @user11638654 thanks for that. np.select gives you a faster alternative for if elif and else statements(for you future ref :))

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do this. Use `map` to satisfy your requirements for each column and create a function to store those conditions:

```
def f(x):
    y = float(x)
    if y<=0.01 and y>0:
        return '***'
    elif y<=0.05 and y>0.01:
        return '**'
    elif y<=0.1 and y>0.05:
        return '*'
    else:
        return x

for col in C:
    C[col] = C[col].map(f)
print(C)
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0  ***  ***
1  ***  ***
2   **   **
3   **   **
4    *    *
5    *    *
```